# Social Networking Add-on for ExpressionEngine

Tags: social

I searched for some Expressioneinge social networking add-on that would allow me to have some "friends" functionality for ExpressEngine at [devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com/).

So far, I only found one plugin, [Friends](http://www.solspace.com/docs/friends/) that allows me to do so.

I am just curious. Are there no other Expresssion Engine plugin that has this type of functionality?

Answer (score 3):

If you need some simple function, you can look to [Buddies](http://www.intoeetive.com/index.php/comments/buddies-are-now-a-module-add-social-network-features-to-your-site-easily)

> This module enables users to have buddies/friends/followers just like
>   in many popular social networks and blogging systems.
>
> The users are able to add/remove others as their buddies. The lists of
>   buddies added by user and also who added him can be displayed. You can
>   also display the total numbers and make various checks.

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider [Messaging](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/messaging), which incorporates funtional from Buddies module. These two use EE built-in buddies/blocked database table (yes, this functional already exists in EE, but it does not natively provide tools to manage user relations on front-end)

Another (more expensive) alternative is [Friends](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/friends) from Solspace